# ImageMagic for php slow compared to GD

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick, gd

I run a small benchmark. same simple text drawing operation with GD and ImageMagick See code below.

On dev server the GD version runs in 1.9 sec and the ImageMagic in 7.3 sec. This is consistant across multiple tests.

On Linux the GD ver runs in 2.5 sec and IM in 4 sec (both including roundtip but the tests were done multiple time on the same server/client and its consistent)

What makes IM slower than GD? Is there a way to optimize it What can I do to get the same performance?

Benchmark code GD:

```
$base_image=imagecreatetruecolor ( 350, 700 );

$white  = imagecolorallocatealpha($base_image, 255, 255, 255, 100);
imagefill($base_image , 0, 0, $white);

imagealphablending($base_image, true);
imagesavealpha($base_image, true);


$black = imagecolorallocatealpha ($base_image, 0,0,0, 1);

for ($i =0; $i<700; $i ++) {

imagettftext($base_image, 13, 0, 20,  $i, $black, './arial.ttf', "Hello World!"); 

imagettftext($base_image, 13, 0, 20,  $i, $black, './arib____.ttf', "Hello World!");

imagettftext($base_image, 13, 0, 20,  $i, $black, './verdana.ttf', "Hello World!");

imagettftext($base_image, 13, 0, 20,  $i, $black, './trebuc.ttf', "Hello World!");

imagettftext($base_image, 13, 0, 20,  $i, $black, './georgia.ttf', "Hello World!");

}


header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($base_image);
```

Benchmark code IM:

```
$canvas = new Imagick();

$canvas->newImage(350, 700, "white");

$draw = new ImagickDraw();



$draw->setFontSize(13*96/72);

for ($i =0; $i<700; $i ++) {    

$draw->setFont('./arial.ttf');
$draw->annotation(20, $i, "Hello World!");

$draw->setFont('./arib____.ttf');
$draw->annotation(20, $i, "Hello World!");

$draw->setFont('./verdana.ttf');
$draw->annotation(20, $i, "Hello World!");

$draw->setFont('./trebuc.ttf');
$draw->annotation(20, $i, "Hello World!");

$draw->setFont('./georgia.ttf');
$draw->annotation(20, $i, "Hello World!");

}

$canvas->drawImage($draw);

$canvas->setImageFormat('png');
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $canvas;
```

GD info

```
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  2.1.1-dev
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.5.2
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPEG Support    enabled
libJPEG Version 8
PNG Support enabled
libPNG Version  1.2.50
WBMP Support    enabled
XPM Support enabled
libXpm Version  30411
XBM Support enabled
WebP Support    enabled
```

Imagick Info

```
imagick module  enabled imagick module version  3.1.2 imagick classes   Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator ImageMagick version    ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2016-06-01 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org ImageMagick copyright    Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC ImageMagick release date 2016-06-01 ImageMagick number of supported formats: 204 ImageMagick supported formats   3FR, A, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, B, BGR, BGRA, BIE, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, C, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DNG, DPX, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, FAX, FITS, FRACTAL, FTS, G, G3, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GROUP4, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, ICB, ICO, ICON, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, J2C, J2K, JBG, JBIG, JNG, JP2, JPC, JPEG, JPG, JPX, K, K25, KDC, LABEL, M, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAP, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, O, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG24, PNG32, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, R, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RLA, RLE, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VST, WBMP, WMV, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, Y, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV

Directive   Local Value Master Value imagick.locale_fix 0   0 imagick.progress_monitor  0   0
```

Comment: No idea if it makes a difference, but maybe try doing all your `arial` font stuff first, then all your `arib` stuff rather than keep changing fonts and reading font files. Just a guess - not tested. By the way, the IM version runs in 1.9s on my Mac with v6.9

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to GD working with bit-depth=8 versus IM using bit-depth=16.  Try

```
$draw -> setImageDepth ( 8 );
```

Alternatively, if you have control over your server, try installing the "Q8" build of ImageMagick in place of the "Q16" build that you have now (and while you're at it, get a current version of ImageMagick; 6.7.7 is very old).